How to implement constrained optimisation with Lagrange multiplier?
I am trying to implement a version of the Lagrange multiplier in delocalised internal coordinates as described by Jon Baker (J. Comput. Chem. 18, 1997, 1079). A description of the method that's not behind paywall can be found here.
I have the code for the delocalised internal coordinates, and it works with minimisations. The main issue is identifying the constraint modes in the Lagrangian hessian.
In this method, the constraints are setup as Lagrange multipliers:
$$L(x, \lambda) = F(x) - \sum \lambda C_i(x)$$
where $C_i(x)$ is a constraint. Then the second derivative of the Lagrangian function is calculated
$$\nabla^2L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 d^2L/dx_j dx_k & d^2L / dx_j d\lambda_i \\\ d^2L / d\lambda_i dx_j & d^2L / d\lambda_j d\lambda_i \end{pmatrix}$$
And then the paper shows that the top left terms in the Lagrangian hessian are essentially the molecular Hessian terms. The top right and bottom left terms are unit vectors and the bottom right terms are all zero.
I have managed to construct the Hessian of the Lagrangian. The problem is that when the quasi-Newton (P-RFO) step has to be taken, the correct constraint modes have to be identified in the eigenvectors of the Hessian - these modes are followed uphill. It is fine if the molecular Hessian is positive definite - but in many molecules which I am testing - this is not the case.
The paper says that the constraint modes can be identified by their large weighting in the Lagrange multiplier variable. But I am not sure how to implement this in code when there are multiple constraints - so multiple constraint modes. I have tried choosing the eigenvectors which have the largest absolute value individual component for the multiplier variable. I have also tried choosing the Hessian eigenvectors where the sum of the absolute value of multiplier components are the highest. However, none of these worked and the optimisation often diverges by following non-constraint modes upwards.
I would like to know how the constraint eigenvectors in the Lagrangian Hessian can be identified? Any advice is appreciated but please do not recommend anything along the lines of not using Lagrange multipliers (I want to be able to handle geometries which are far from satisfying the constraints).

I want to be able to handle geometries which are far from satisfying the constraints -- isn't that precisely the problem? The non-positive-definiteness of the Lagrangian Hessian is telling you that the geometries violate constraint severely enough that simple linearization is not strong enough to converge to a purely constrained solution -- not without significantly distorting the molecule in other ways.

@ShernRenTee Yes - so I want to take a step that moves towards satisfying the constraints - even if it can't do that in a single step. Its fine to move towards the constraint in small steps as long as there is progress - but what I see in my tests is unpredictable jumps in the geometry.

I would not expect numerical methods to converge when started from poor guesses in general. This particular case is amenable to simple thought experiment. Suppose you have two particles, harmonically bonded; you try Lagrangian constraint on their distance, but begin with them very close to each other. There will be many initial velocities and lambdas that leave the bond and Lagrangian forces parallel, indefinitely, for large enough timestep, so the system "sloshes" and can never settle to either the unconstrained or constrained minimum.
